# Не могу исправить ошибку при работе с mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Код:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE login = '$login'");
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$end = $array['id'];
$error = mysqli_error($db);
echo($error $end);
mysqli_close($db);
exit();
```

Ошибка:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$end' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/LHVideo/Auth/auth.php on line 15
```

Подскажите, как исправить

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны разделять параметры, передаваемые `echo()`:

```
echo($arg1, $arg2);
```

Либо так

```
echo $arg1, $arg2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция [echo()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php) принимает один или несколько аргументов которые разделены запятой.

```
echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )
```

Вам нужно исправить `echo($error $end);` на `echo($error, $end);`